# Rewrite method to decide the ShowLevel based on roles

Tags: java

I have different `roles` in my system.

1. HOD
2. Staff
3. Non staff

I am having a form at the front end and fields shall be visible to only users with specific roles.

The `ShowInGui` levels are like this:

1. Show to All
2. Show to staff/HOD
3. Show to HOD

Any other do not show

I am planning to write a method which will take the user role and decides the access.

Could this method be better written?

```
public boolean canBeShownInGUI(Role role, int showInGui) {
    if (showInGui == 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (showInGui == 2 && (role == Role.HOD || role == Role.STAFF)) {
        return true;
    } else if (showInGui == 3 && role == Role.HOD) {
        return true;
    } else 
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: @h.j.k.Apologies. Now I have updated my code and fixed compile errors as well. Will you take a look at it.

Comment: @Patan as pointed out by Heslacher now, you have other problems too... please scrutinize your posted code again. If you are still unable to spot any errors then I too think that this should be closed.

Comment: And I can't help but feel this code has not been tested at all either, the results are "just plain wrong". Appears to show a disappointing lack of effort to follow the on-topic criteria.

Comment: @h.j.k I am really sorry. Due to security problems I could not post the original code but now I have posted the correct code. Could you please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume `Role` is an enum (if it is not, it should be). An enum is a great candidate for a switch statement, and it also makes the conditions very clear:

```
switch (role) {
    case HOD:
        return showInGui >= 1;
    case STAFF:
        return showInGui == 1 || showInGui == 2;
}
return showInGui == 1;
```

Note that, if you want you can embed that logic in to the enum itself, and have a simple call to an enum method:

```
return role.isVisible(showInGui);
```

Additionally, if you reverse the values of the showInGui to be:

```
0 -> nobody
1 -> HOD only
2 -> HOD & STAFF
3 -> everyone
```

then your logic is simplified further to:

```
switch (role) {
    case HOD:
        return showInGui >= 1;
    case STAFF:
        return showInGui >= 2;
}
return showInGui >= 3;
```